# C++ Clion Debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, ide, clion

I encountered with an error `C:/Users/batuh/......./Term_Project.exe: No such file or directory` however as you can see in the screenshot directory correct and also there is a file with a name `"Term_project.exe"`. Any idea?

My CmakeLists.txt (I don't know how to use Cmake if there is an error, please don't blame to me, this is automated Cmake.)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Term_Project VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(Term_Project main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Here is my screenshot [image: error].

Comment: You are including CTest and enabled the testing.  Can you do a "hello world" with that CMakefile?

Comment: Do you mean that can I run a cpp file? If this is your question, I can run a cpp file with bunch of pointers.

Comment: Try to remove include(CTest) and enable_testing() because I don't see tests linked to the project so this including is useless

Answer (score 1):

The debugger cannot find the location of the files, because your path name contains non-ASCII characters.

From the screenshot you can see that in the name of your OneDrive there is non-ASCII character.

**You must change your path of the files to something containing only ASCII characters!**